# React-native: requireNativeComponent: "RNGestureHandlerRootView" was not found in the UIManager after upgrading to latest version react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6, react-native-gesture-handler

I just upgrading my react native project (CLI) from 0.66.1 to 0.70.6. I run perfectly on iOS, but it occur this error when I run on android.[[image]].
My package.json:

```
"react-native": "0.70.6",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
 "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
   "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.14",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.5",
```

How can I fix this issue? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had the same problem. Here's the solution:

You need add react-native-gesture-handler

```
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler or npm install react-native-gesture-handler
```

and Add this in App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```